# Can "when" be used this way: It was the first time when...?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

In the following sentence, can "when" be used? ("x" means nothing in that spot.)

> It was the first time that/when/x Peter had seen a black horse.

Comment: No, _when_ can't be used, but _that_ can be omitted in informal language.